# Object #<Object> has no method 'findUser'

Tags: node.js, mongoose, cloud9-ide

I working through the Lynda.com course on the MEAN stack and this error keeps occurring. I'm not real sure where to look. I have already scoured through numerous Google pages looking for anything that may give me a clue

This is where I call findUser.

```
  module.exports = function() {
  var passport = require('passport');
  var passportLocal = require('passport-local');
  var userService = require('../services/user-service');

  passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy({usernameField: 'email'}, function(email, password, next) {
    userService.findUser(email, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (!user || user.password !== password) {
        return next(null, null);
      }
      next(null, user);
    });
  }));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, next) {
    next(null, user.email);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(email, next) {
    userService.findUser(email, function(err, user) {
      next(err, user);
    });
  });
};
```

This is the error that I get when trying to "login" with user information verified in the database.

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'findUser'
    at Strategy.module.exports [as _verify] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/auth/passport-config.js:7:17)
    at Strategy.authenticate (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:90:12)
    at attempt (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:341:16)
    at authenticate (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:342:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at proto.handle.c (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
```

Here is the user-services.js file

```
var User = require('../models/user').User;

exports.addUser = function(user, next) {
  var newUser = new User({
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName,
    roomNumber: user.roomNumber,
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  });

  newUser.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    next(null);
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you please provide the source for the file `../services/user-service`

Comment: Mutahhir, you were correct. Somehow, I skipped a video where that part got setup. Everything works as intended now. Thank you all for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your userService exported object doesn't have findUser method.

Export it by adding `module.exports.findUser = findUser;` if the name of your original function is `findUser`. If you're already exporting an object like say:

```
module.exports = {
  foo: foo
};
```

Just add `findUser: findUser` to that object.